# How do I supply a secret to az containerapps compose

Tags: azure, docker-compose, containers, command-line-interface, secrets

I'm trying to set-up my first azure containerapps cloud deployment.

As multiply containers are involved, I want to utilize the sub command

`az containerapp compose create`

referencing our private docker registry (command line parameters `--registry-username`, `--registry-password`).

It seems that the registry password will be stored in a secret; the automatic secret creation fails due to naming conventions:

```
$ az containerapp compose create --environment my-containers --resource-group my-rg --registry-server dockerregistry.acme.com --registry-username benjamin.sailer@acme.com --registry-password <my-pw> --compose-file-path ./compose.yaml
Adding registry password as a secret with name "dockerregistryacmecom-benjamin.sailer@acme.com"
(ContainerAppInvalidPropertyValue) Property 'secrets.name' has an invalid value 'dockerregistryacmecom-benjamin.sailer@acme.com'. A value must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character.
...
```

Now I tried to set-up a secret up-front, to reference it in the command, like documentation states:

```
--registry-password
The password to log in to container registry. If stored as a secret, value must start with 'secretref:' followed by the secret name.
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/compose?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-compose-create).

But now I'm facing a chicken-egg-problem:  To create a containerapp secret, I have to reference an existing containerapp:

```
az containerapp secret set --resource-group my-rg --name docker-registry --secrets username=benjamin.sailer@acme.com password=<my-pw>
The containerapp 'docker-registry' does not exist
```

c.f.:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-secret-set

I'm most probably mixing up secret types (a secret visible inside a container is systematically different from a secret that is used to connect to a registry with the purpose of spinning up the container), but the documentation is rather thin here.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint.

**Update:**

Finally I managed to resolve this with terraform, where I could manage the secret in combination with container creation *and at the same time* specify the secret's name explicitly; this - however - does not use the original az sub command "compose"; it seems to me that this path is not yet well finished; e.g. there's no support for tearing down an compose infrastructure :(.

Azure itself does seem to promote "managed identities" instead, but I'm not sure whether that works for non-Azure registries.

Following github issues it seems that direct configurative access from container apps to key vault secrets is still on their todo-list, while should be out as a preview soon:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/608

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to create an **azure containerapps**

I have created an **Azure Key Vault** and stored the password in the **Key Vault** using the following commands

1. Store the **Container Registery** secret in **Keyvault** using below command.

   ```
   az keyvault secret set --vault-name kamalikeyvault --name registry-password --value "upIWaixxxxxxxxxxxJ/UD/BeqJOHxceYlg8i+ACRAf7Lvc"
   ```

   2. Create an container app using below commands.

   ```
    $s = az keyvault secret show --name "registry-password" --vault-name "venkatvaulttest"
            $r=$s | ConvertFrom-Json
            $result=$r.value        
            $result
            az containerapp compose create --environment "venkatcontainerregistry" --resource-group "vnkat-RG" --registry-server venkatcontainerregistry.azurecr.io --registry-username "venkatcontainerregistry" --registry-password $result  --compose-file-path /home/dasari/docker-compose.yaml
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above commands **Azure Container** app is created successfully in portal.

[image]

Comment: Hi VenkatV,
thanks a lot for providing this solution, however this is not exactly what I'm looking for.  What you're actually doing is:
a) store the secret in a keyvault; b) retrieve it from the keyvault to your client; c) use this secret in a client's command to generate the container app.
In contrast to this I was looking for a method to store the secret in some azure-store (be it keyvault) and then reference the secret-location in the command to create the container app (utilizing the "secretref:"-prefix).  However, I found out that this is currently not possible according to the docs...